# How to get response time taken by each page via Jmeter, While there are multiple API calls being made on page load?

Tags: jmeter

We have a application that contains 10 to 11 http samples in each page, we need to find the response time of each web page?, how to calculate?
I have used transaction controller, but that gives sum of all samples response time,
which in reality is very huge like 120000ms (120sec) , but wen manually checked application takes only 3 sec ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the individual response times in the output file of your test run.

1) Add a 'View Results Tree' Listener to your test plan.

2) Specify a filename in the 'Write results to file section'
[image: you can refer to this image]

3) Run your tests. Once the test run is complete, you can open the file [which you had given in step 2] and check the response time of each individual request.

Note: The second column called 'elapsed' is the measure of response time.